# fopen() function being skipped - No file is created | PHP

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

I have been working on this for a couple of weeks now and yet again I am facing file issues. This sheet of code first gets all the entries existing in a database, then, after obtaining a series of ids, launches the same query with an additional `WHERE` clause to search for specific entries belonging to customers.

Finally, compares both resulting arrays in search of any entry that exists in the db but has not been asigned to any customer to print them onto a csv file so the user launching the code can attend the issues preventing those entries from being linked to a customer.

I have been suffering some issues in the past regarding files and permissions, but this time no error appears, no message alerting me that I don't have the authority to open a file in the desired location or anything.

I tried inserting some `var_dump()` along the sheet to see if the process really got to the `fopen()` which it does. It simply skips it, no file is created and no data written.

I looked at the server logs but found nothing and I have errors and warnings enabled.

This would take all entries from the database.

```php
$stmtOutgoing = $connAccounting->prepare("SELECT a.`zone`, b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id`, b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, count(*) AS llamadas, SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))) AS duracion, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100) AS total, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100)/SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))) AS precio  
                                            FROM `billing`.billing_zones a INNER JOIN cdr b 
                                            ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id` 
                                            WHERE source_provider_id = :reseller_id 
                                            GROUP BY b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, a.`zone` 
                                            ORDER BY total desc");
$stmtOutgoing->execute(array('reseller_id' => $reseller));




foreach ($stmtOutgoing as $row) {
    
    array_push($totalEntries, $row);
    echo "CDR Entry Added ";
}
```

After obtaining the ids, there would be a `loop` to insert all of them inside this query:

```php
foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
    if ($invoice['date'] >= $minDateSearchTstmp && !empty($invoice["customFields"]) && $invoice["customFields"][0]["field"] == "ID_EXTERNAL" && $invoice["customFields"][0]["value"] != "") {

        $z = 0;
        while ( isset($invoice['customFields'][$z]['field']) && $invoice['customFields'][$z]['field'] == 'ID_EXTERNAL' ) {

            $source_external_subscriber_id = $invoice["customFields"][0]["value"]; 

            renewConnection($connAccounting, $stmtOutgoing, $stmtIncoming);
            require '../connections/accountingConnection.php';



            /*Outgoing*/
            $stmtOutgoing = $connAccounting->prepare("SELECT a.`zone`, b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id`, b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, count(*) AS llamadas, SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))) AS duracion, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100) AS total, SUM((b.`source_customer_cost`)/100)/SUM((CEIL(b.`duration`))) AS precio  
                                            FROM `billing`.billing_zones a INNER JOIN cdr b 
                                            ON a.`id` = b.`source_customer_billing_zone_id` 
                                            WHERE source_external_subscriber_id = :source_external_subscriber_id AND source_provider_id = :reseller_id 
                                            GROUP BY b.`source_external_subscriber_id`, a.`zone` 
                                            ORDER BY total desc");
                $stmtOutgoing->execute(array('source_external_subscriber_id' => $source_external_subscriber_id, 'reseller_id' => $reseller));

            
            foreach ($stmtOutgoing as $row) {
                
                array_push($holdedEntries, $row);
                echo "Holded Entry Added ";
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Finally, this code was supposed to generate the file and populate it with the info obtained:

```php
foreach ($totalEntries as $tEntry) {
    if (!in_array($tEntry, $holdedEntries)) {
        array_push($unassignedEntries, $tEntry);
    }
}


$fp = fopen('./unassigned_cdr_entries/entradasSinAsignar'.$fileDate.'.csv', 'w');
$delimiter = ',';
$enclosure = '"';
$escape_char = "\\";

foreach ($unassignedEntries as $unassignedEntry) {
    var_dump($unassignedEntry);
    fputcsv($fp, $unassignedEntry, $delimiter, $enclosure, $escape_char);
}


fclose($fp);
```

The original permissions for the files were these:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   152 Sep  4 13:26 'Resultados diferencias Cdr-Holded'
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6358 Sep  4 14:24  fetch_repeated_and_similar_ids.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3564 Sep  4 13:26  fetch_repeated_ids.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3733 Sep  4 13:26  fetch_similar_ids.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6057 Sep  4 13:26  holded-cdr_data_difference.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  1 16:57  repeated_ids
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14661 Sep  4 13:26 'unassignedCdrEntriesTest(Old).php'
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Sep  7 10:04  unassigned_cdr_entries
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7616 Sep  7 16:23  unassigned_cdr_entries.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 19613 Sep  4 13:26  unassigned_cdr_entries_for_two_months.php
```

I tried with `chmod 766` and `chmod 777` to no avail. As I said not even a warning telling me I can't open a file there due to insufficient permissions. You may also see the `var_dump()` placed at the last `foreach() loop`. The process gets there and the array is not empty as there are two test entries not assigned to anyone. Also as a recap, no other warning or error found using:

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Any idea or suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try using an absolute path for the filename, I suspect it's writing to a different directory than you expect.

Comment: Thank you for replying! I tried doing a `realpath()` and storing the string in variable to pass to fopen() but still did not work.

Comment: If you give `realpath()` the same relative path, it will return the path to the same wrong file.

Comment: print the value that `realpath()` returns and make sure it's what you expected.

Comment: If you're not getting an error, it must be writing the output somewhere, it's just not where you think it is.

Comment: `/home/PROJECT/DAILY_BILLING/control_functions/unassigned_cdr_entries` is the path returned which is right, I am totally clueless as to what could be happening!

Comment: I don't know if this could be related but up until I tried using `chmod` I could connect to my server using ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx withouth needing to input the password but now I am asked to provide it, also happening with scp command to upload files.

Comment: The most important rule in debugging, and indeed all of programming: Break The Problem Down. We don't need to know 90% of what you've told us here; and more importantly, _you_ shouldn't need to think about 90% of what you've said while debugging your current problem. Step through the code with a debugger or a series of die statements, figure out if the `fopen` call is even being reached. If it is, _delete everything before that line_, and run some code that just puts some known data into a known file name. Keep narrowing it down until you have a [mcve] to show us, or have fixed it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to post the solution I found as an answer. The issue here lied in the fact that everytime I overwrote the old files with new ones, for reasons that I don't know, the owner and permissions of the files changed, thus preventing apache user `www-data` from creating files.

The prject folder was being sent via ssh, so whenever I had to update something I would just use `chown` and `chmod` to restore user and permissions of the folder/file affected to `www-data` and `755` respectively.